# What is the difference between SalesforceCanvasJavascriptSDK and SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK?

Tags: canvas

When I working on a POC for a client I came across the two repositories in github which is

[SalesforceCanvasJavascriptSDK](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceCanvasJavascriptSDK)

[SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK)

Is that the second one which is SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK specifically used for the platform which does not support javascript? Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TO implement Canvas implementation you will eventually be needing **SalesforceCanvasJavascriptSDK** and this has libraries to assist with authentication and data fetching using REST API .

> SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK uses one or more libraries present in the **SalesforceCanvasJavascriptSDK** library and a sample Java web app is set up on heruko and this shows how to include Js files  of the SalesforceCanvasFrameworkSDK and call API and authenticate

```
<head>

<title>Hello World Canvas Example</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sdk/css/canvas.css" />

<!-- Include all the canvas JS dependencies in one file -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/sdk/js/canvas-all.js"></script>
<!-- Third part libraries, substitute with your own -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/json2.js"></script>

<script>
    if (self === top) {
        // Not in Iframe
        alert("This canvas app must be included within an iframe");
    }

    Sfdc.canvas(function() {
        var sr = JSON.parse('<%=signedRequestJson%>');
        // Save the token
        Sfdc.canvas.oauth.token(sr.oauthToken);
        Sfdc.canvas.byId('username').innerHTML = sr.context.user.fullName;
    });

</script>
```

For example you can see the app has a page  which utilizes the canvas-all.js from the SalesforceCanvasJavascriptSDK

Comment: Thanks Mohit. I am little bit confused here and thats why the question. Can you please tell if there is any alternative way to use for the platform which does not support javascript? Because i am trying to use SAP webdynpro and SAP webgui as canvas app and both of them does not support js libraries. Any thoughts or workaround for this ?

Comment: @BaskaranS we need jaavascript and browser technologies for sure to bring those as page in SFDC .So without Java script i dont know whether its feasible to do that

Comment: Correct. I agree with you. But the issue is both SAP webdynpro and webGUI allowing us to write code for web pages but in ABAP which when run it renders into an html on the browsers. ABAP does not support js is the big issue from my side. Ok. I agree with your input and going to select this as an answer.